# Share one service instance in Angular 2 RC5

Tags: angular, typescript

I used to share one service instance by declaring it as a `viewInjectors` inside my `@Component` like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-sel',
    viewInjectors: [SharedService],
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    pipes: [MyPipe]
})
```

This solution doesn't work anymore in Angular 2 RC5. Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you mean `viewProviders`?

Comment: Where do you want to share it? The whole application or the descendants?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `viewProviders` create multiple instances... I would like to share it among multiple `Components` inside the whole app

Comment: No provider creates multiple instances. There is always one instance per provider.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Well, when I initialize a variable in the service from one component and try to retrieve it in another, I get an empty variable.

Comment: This is because you have two instances of the component where the provider is added and therefore you have two providers. If you add the provider on a parent component, then you get only one instance for two children because there is a shared provider on one parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to share a service for your application or your module, you need to declare it when bootstrapping the application or when defining your module.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

or

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [SharedService], // <----
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Don't forget to remove the service from `providers` attributes of your components...

Comment: Looks good! Do I have to import the service in my components?

Comment: In fact, no because of hierarchical injectors. If you do that the single will be at the level of the component and not above (application or module)... That's what Günter means by "one instance per provider". You need to be very careful at this level ;-)